# Install and update R offline in Centos

Tags: r, centos, cran

I've been searching a little and found a lot for installing R packages offline in centos,but what i found is assuming that you already have R base installed,what i need is  assuming you need to install everything in an offline Centos server, how do you install R base package?

Comment: mount your centos iso and use it as a repo

Comment: But that would work only if R is inside official Centos repos right?